# Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

this is my appconfig file

```
package com.example.mflixmovierentalapp.config;

import javax.sql.DataSource;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;

import java.util.Properties;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.example.mflixmovierentalapp") // This will include your HelloController
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages ="com.example.mflixmovierentalapp.repositories") // Ensure this points to your repositories
@EntityScan(basePackages = "com.example.mflixmovierentalapp.model")
public class AppConfig {
    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/movierental?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC"); // Added serverTimezone parameter
        dataSource.setUsername("root");
        dataSource.setPassword("root");
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emf = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        emf.setDataSource(dataSource());
        emf.setPackagesToScan("com.example.mflixmovierentalapp.model");
        

        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        emf.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);

        // If you have additional properties for JPA, set them here
        // For example:
         Properties jpaProperties = new Properties();
         jpaProperties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect");
         emf.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties);

        return emf;
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory.getObject());
    }
}
```

and this is my entity class

```
package com.example.mflixmovierentalapp.model;

import com.example.mflixmovierentalapp.enums.Role;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "`User`")// Using backticks for case sensitivity in some databases
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "userID", nullable = false)
    private Integer userID;

    public Integer getUserID() {
        return userID;
    }

    @Setter
    @Column(name="username", nullable = false)
    private String username;

    @Setter
    @Column(name="email", nullable = false)
    private String email;

    @Setter
    @Column(name="password", nullable = false)
    private String password;

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    @Setter
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name="role")
    private Role role;

    @Setter
    @Column(name="isActive")
    private Boolean isActive;

    @Setter
    @Column(name="contactDetails")
    private String contactDetails;

}
```

what is wrong here why this is not able to find the entity ?

I had tried changing the package path to this `mflixmovierentalapp.model` but then i am getting error for the repository scan
`Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository' defined in com.example.mflixmovierentalapp.repositories.UserRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on AppConfig: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.example.mflixmovierentalapp.model.User`

Comment: As the error log says, it occurs because the userRepository of userServiceImpl is not properly injected with dependency.

There appears to be no bean registration setting corresponding to the AppConfig class.

Could you upload the userServiceImpl and userRepository class codes?